# Get resource path of a file in java using Path class

Tags: java, resources

I'm new to Java, someone please let me know how to get resource path of a file instead of using entire path. Below is the code I've.

```
Path file = Paths.get("/home/Documents/src/test/resources/files/sample.txt");
```

I need something like getResource("files/sample.txt").

Comment: You are aware that proceeding this way means you won't be able to use this code if your code is packaged as a jar? Why do you want the path exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
URI uri = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/files/sample.txt").toURI(); 
Path path = Paths.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are searching for something like :

```
Path resolve(String other)
```

please look at javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.lang.String-)